# Изменение формы регистрации при выборе другого элемента списка

Tags: html

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе другого элемента списка менялась форма регистрации?

[image: скриншот формы]

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select name="demo-category" id="demo-category">
        <option value="1">Seaman / Job Seeker</option>
        <option value="1">Crewing Company</option>
        <option value="1">Shipowner</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Сейчас выбран `Seaman`, нужно чтобы форма поменялась при нажатие на `Crewing company`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно менять атрибут `data-state` формы при изменении элемента списка. В зависимости от значения этого атрибута можно скрывать элементы, имеющие определённые классы. Можно создать три класса `hide-if-seamen`, `hide-if-crewing` и `hide-if-shipowner`, и добавить их к нужным элементам. Например, так:

```js
$('#demo-category').change(function() {
  $('#form').attr('data-state', $(this).find(':selected').data('state'));
});
```

```css
#form[data-state="seamen"] .hide-if-seamen {
  display: none;
}

#form[data-state="crewing"] .hide-if-crewing {
  display: none;
}

#form[data-state="shipowner"] .hide-if-shipowner {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form" class="select-wrapper" data-state="seamen">
  <select name="demo-category" id="demo-category">
        <option data-state="seamen" value="1">Seaman / Job Seeker</option>
        <option data-state="crewing" value="2">Crewing Company</option>
        <option data-state="shipowner" value="3">Shipowner</option>
    </select>

  <div>Показывается всегда</div>
  <div class="hide-if-crewing hide-if-shipowner">Показывается только для Seaman</div>
  <div class="hide-if-seamen hide-if-shipowner">Показывается только для Crewing</div>
  <div class="hide-if-shipowner">Показывается для Seaman и Crewing (но не для Shipowner)</div>
</div>
```